# ctypes cast c_uint64 to c_char_p

Tags: python, casting, ctypes, sizeof

`from ctypes import *` and

```
In [27]: sizeof(c_char_p)
Out[27]: 8

In [28]: sizeof(c_uint64)
Out[28]: 8

In [29]: cast(c_uint64(0), c_char_p)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/az/Programmierung/PyCPython/<ipython console> in <module>()

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.pyc in cast(obj, typ)
    479 _cast = PYFUNCTYPE(py_object, c_void_p, py_object, py_object)(_cast_addr)
    480 def cast(obj, typ):
--> 481     return _cast(obj, obj, typ)
    482 
    483 _string_at = PYFUNCTYPE(py_object, c_void_p, c_int)(_string_at_addr)

ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Why does the `cast` fail?

Is there any alternative to `ctypes.cast` which always works if `sizeof` both types is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going this way now:

```
def isPointerType(t):
    if issubclass(t, _ctypes._Pointer): return True
    return False

def getValueOf(obj):
    if isPointerType(obj.__class__):
        return cast(obj, c_void_p).value
    else:
        return obj.value

def static_cast(obj, t):
    newObj = t()
    if isPointerType(t):
        cast(pointer(obj), POINTER(c_void_p)).contents.value = getValueOf(obj)
    else:
        newObj.value = getValueOf(obj)
    return newObj
```

Looks somewhat complicated but I haven't really figured out a simpler way.

Answer (score 3):

Is the c_uint64 a memory address?  If so, then you can do this:

```
>>> n = c_uint64(1234567890) #assume this is a valid memory address...beware of segfaults
>>> p = c_char_p(n.value)
>>> #or..
>>> p.value = n.value #special semantics for c_char_p - accepts both addresses and strings
```

(see http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p)

Or, if what you want to do is reinterpret the value stored in the c_uint64 as an 8 byte null-terminated character buffer then you need to cast a pointer to the c_uint64 as the c_char_p...

```
>>> n = c_uint64(ord("A"))
>>> n
c_ulong(65L)
>>> p = cast(pointer(n), c_char_p)
>>> p
c_char_p(47101614291216)
>>> p.value
'A'
```

It looks like ctypes will protect you from buffer overruns if it's not null-terminated:

```
>>> n2 = c_uint64(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
>>> p2 = cast(pointer(n2), c_char_p)
>>> p2.value[0]
'\xff'
>>> p2.value
'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> p2.value[9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

**UPDATE in response to Albert's comment:**

> I want to know why cast doesn't work here

The answer to why is in the documentation and the code - http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast

> ctypes.cast(obj, type)
>       This function is similar to the cast operator in C. It returns a new instance of type which points to the same memory block as obj.
>   type must be a pointer type, **and obj must be an object that can be
>   interpreted as a pointer.**

The contract is enforced in the [code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r267/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py?revision=88851&view=markup) as such:

```
_cast = PYFUNCTYPE(py_object, c_void_p, py_object, py_object)(_cast_addr)
def cast(obj, typ):
    return _cast(obj, obj, typ)
```

So the first argument to cast (the object) must be convertible to a c_void_p.  In the [source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r267/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c?annotate=88851), check out c_void_p_from_param().  This is where conversion to c_void_p is done.  There are converters for Python integers, Python strings, Python unicode strings, c_void_p, ctypes array/pointer, byref results, function pointers, c_char_p/c_wchar_p, and any object that has the _as_parameter_() method defined.

There are no converters for ctypes integer objects.  I am only looking at 2.6 code (as that's what you're using), so that might not be the case in 2.7 or 3.x.

As for the rationale - that question would have to be presented to the developers.

> ...if there is a generic version which always works (for all cases, not
>   just c_char_p).

As far as I know, the solution is just as I showed with the first example.  Construct pointers with or assign to the value member of pointer objects with Python integers (the converter knows how to convert from Python integers).  cast() will not work because that's how it was implemented.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I know how to cast anything to `c_char_p`. I want to know why `cast` doesn't work here and if there is a generic version which always works (for all cases, not just `c_char_p`).

Comment: Hm, the first example doesn't work for pointer types, for unions and for structures. And also not for arrays.

Comment: Now I am really confused about what it is you're trying to do.  Are you actually trying to arbitrarily cast data types (not pointers to data types) to other types? I would guess not... If you are reinterpreting buffers, then you must cast a pointer of the "from type" to the pointer of the "to type". Please explicitly state the use cases so that it's clear what question it is I'm answering. The only real question that I can infer is of fundamental data type conversions are not working as you expected (int -> ptr).

Comment: I'm searching for an exact `static_cast` equivalent which works exactly the same way as `static_cast` (in C++). And maybe (optionally) even more generally.

Answer (score 1):

You have to obtain a pointer to the value, check this:

```
In [29]: i = c_uint32(0x30313233)

In [30]: cast(pointer(i), c_char_p).value
Out[30]: '3210'
```